# Minimum 'Long press and hold' duration to get context menu in touch devices

Tags: windows, browser, touch, contextmenu, long-press

Long press and release of hand in touch screens(win 10) imitates "Mouse - Right click" resulting in context menu. What is minimum press and hold time to trigger context menu in win 10. From various resources I understand that 2 TAPs within a gap of 300ms is considered as double click/double tap.

Comment: I don't think it's changed from 500ms in any current versions, but you can always use `getLongPressTimeout()` to get the exact value, as described in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM. I have changed the question a little bit. I am more concerned about browsers running in Windows based touch devices instead of Android.